# How to properly set Oauth2 servers into a Spring existing API?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-security, oauth

I'm implementing a Oauth2 server into an existing REST api to add security to some parts of it.
The problem is: if I doesn't declare the @configuration of the ResourceServer and AuthorizationServer inside the main class, the spring security doesn't load the configuration, so I can't acces to the API.

I want to put this configuration in an external class in a different package, but I'm so new on Spring and I can't find the way to do it properly.

So my external configuration file, **that works if his content is inside the main class** but no if is in a external file:

**SecurityConf.java**

```
@RestController
@Configuration
public class Security {

@RequestMapping("/")
public String home() {
    return "Hello World";
}

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
protected static class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http

            .authorizeRequests()
                            .antMatchers("/features/**").permitAll()
                            .antMatchers("/itineraries/**").permitAll()



            .anyRequest().access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')"); //This makes all other petitions under authorization

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources)
            throws Exception {
        resources.resourceId("sparklr");
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
            throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        clients.inMemory().withClient("my-trusted-client")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code",
                        "refresh_token", "implicit")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
                .scopes("read", "write", "trust").resourceIds("sparklr")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(60).and()
                .withClient("my-client-with-registered-redirect")
                 .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code").authorities("ROLE_CLIENT")
                .scopes("read", "trust").resourceIds("sparklr")
                .redirectUris("http://anywhere?key=value").and()
                .withClient("my-client-with-secret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "password")
                 .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT").scopes("read").resourceIds("sparklr")
                .secret("secret");
        // @formatter:on
    }

}

}
```

And the main class,

**Application.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = SimpleCORSFilter.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.pace.things.model")
public class Application {
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean() {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        registrationBean.setFilter(characterEncodingFilter);
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
        registrationBean.setOrder(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
        return registrationBean;
}    


    public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

So what is that I'm forgetting?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I solved the problem myself on this [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42401181/how-to-add-spring-websecurityconfig-to-an-existing-project) thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Referenced thread](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42442226/edit):

I need to add the WebSecurityConfig to the application context adding this line in the main class declaration:

```
...
@Import(WebSecurityConfig.class)
public class Application   {
...
```

Another thing that I did is upgrade SpringBoot to `1.4.3.RELEASE` and put the main application to root folder:

```
 <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
```

The tree will be, for example:

```
└── com
└── app
    ├── Application.java
    └── config
        └── WebSecurityConfig.java
```

This automatically load all `@Configuration` in son folders.