# How to add Spring WebSecurityConfig to an existing project

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to add to a an existing spring REST api project a simply configuration for WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to test it. But when spring starts it doesn't load the configuration. Maybe I need to add it to the application context but I don't know how to do it.

If I make a `curl localhost:8080/` always get an unauthorized response, so I think that is not loading the configuration, why it is? Or, how I should load it? 
In all the diversed projects that I saw on github, they never do special things to load it! Its maybe because its loading an embbeded servlet first?

This is the simple web security configuration:

```
@SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiringInspection")
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
public void configureAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
    authenticationManagerBuilder
            .userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
            // we don't need CSRF because our token is invulnerable
            .csrf().disable()

            // don't create session
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()

            .authorizeRequests()
            //.antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()

            // allow anonymous resource requests
            .antMatchers(
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    "/",
                    "/*.html",
                    "/favicon.ico",
                    "/**/*.html",
                    "/**/*.css",
                    "/**/*.js",
                    "/**"
            ).permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

    // disable page caching
    httpSecurity.headers().cacheControl();
}
}
```

And this is my Application

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = SimpleCORSFilter.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration    org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ManagementSecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.thing.model")
@RestController
public class Application {


    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean() {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        registrationBean.setFilter(characterEncodingFilter);
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
        registrationBean.setOrder(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
        return registrationBean;
    }    




    public static void main(String[] args) {
                SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
            return "Hello World";
    }
```

**pom.xml dependencies**

```
       <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-referencing</artifactId>
        <version>8.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I need to add the WebSecurityConfig to the application context adding this line in the main class declaration:

```
...
@Import(WebSecurityConfig.class)
public class Application   {
...
```

Another thing that I did is upgrade SpringBoot to `1.4.3.RELEASE` and put the main application to root folder:

```
 <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
```

The tree will be, for example:

```
└── com
└── app
    ├── Application.java
    └── config
        └── WebSecurityConfig.java
```

This automatically load all `@Configuration` in son folders.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/) to learn how to enable web security in Spring projects.

Answer (score 0):

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ClientResourceControllerTest {
```

Above helped me for the same issue.